# Get text on same line HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, web, line

How do I put the address on the same line as "contact me on:" ? I also want one space between them. I was thinking of using float, nut isn't that overkill?

```
<p>Contact me on: 
<address> 
<a href="mailto:me@gmail.com"> 
me@gmail.com
</address>
</a>
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tY9nS/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just don't use `<address>`.... Also you could remove `<p>` [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tY9nS/10/)

Comment: [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tY9nS/13/) Should have been this demo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change **your html** as like this '

```
<address> 
<p>Contact me on: <a href="mailto:me@gmail.com"> 
me@gmail.com</a></p>
   </address>
```

Don't** put the `address` tag in `p` tag put the `p` tag into `address` tag

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tY9nS/6/)**

Comment: Surely the whole point of this question is to get them on the same line without moving `contact me on:` into `<address>`.

Comment: +5 for moving `HTML` yay! xD

Comment: The thing is not about moving HTML, but understanding why this HTML part wasn't standard and clean, and that's why he had trouble. You can't put an address element in a p element. Furthermore, the anchor was open in the address element and closed after.

Comment: You can surely put <p> and <address> a display: inline; but that would have been dirty.

Comment: I understood you still making websites as in 1999.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure why this is, but browsers don't allow an address tag in a p tag.

You can make this work, but you'll need to remove the p { width:100%}. 
The since browsers are setting the address and p tag one after the other, your p tag will consume 100% of the width, thus no more room for the address.

Change the styles to : p,address{ display:inline-block;} and it will work just fine

Answer (score -2):

Another simple way would be to format it in a table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Contact me on:</td>
<td><a href="mailto:me@gmail.com">me@gmail.com</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Otherwise there's the more complicated options where you go into layout using div elements that you can find here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp

Comment: @wf4 Sorry whats wrong with this? This is a perfectly fine way to display information.

Comment: @Mr_Green The question was `How do I put the address on the same line as "contact me on:" ?` and this is a viable option.

Comment: @Ruddy not at all comparable to the above suggestion given by Rohit.. we can do this but think whether is it good or ok atleast?

Comment: Use <table> for tabular information, not for layout purpose guys... Flagged.

Comment: @Mr_Green I see no problem with it. When I ask a question I want as many ways to solve it at possible that way I can pick one that I understand and also is compatible with my layout etc.

Comment: @enguerranws Did you really flag this? It is displaying information and is also not being used as a layout.

Comment: This is not a solution, this is just a way to get more problems. Dirty html code will never solve anything.

Comment: @enguerranws Tables are not dirty at all, you clearly just don't know how to use them if you see a major problem here.

Comment: <table> element should be used to display tabular information like : Email | mail@mail.com | Phone | 12451241 | Name | Joe

Comment: @enguerranws Oh dear.

Comment: @Ruddy we suggest better for asker/OP here. that is why upvoting/downvoting is here on SO. it is not to hurt others feelings.

Comment: Ok good sir, go read some web books or this : http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.1

Comment: @Mr_Green We suggest what we think is best, in this case this poster has gone with a table. Again there is nothing wrong with using this, yes its a little untidy and I wouldn't use it but is still a viable option. Its up to the OP to decide what they would like to use and by the looks of it they have done with fixing the `HTML`. And so I don't have to write another comment. @enguerranws You are talking about using it as a layout, this is **not** a layout. I would guess they have more information after the address, so I see no problem here. Again I wouldn't personally use it.

Comment: @Ruddy sorry, I thought this is not good. so, downvoted it :). btw, man, such a big comment? please cool down. :). to be frank, I am not a  serial downvoter. I do when I don't like any post/suggestion.

Comment: @Mr_Green I'm not saying any of this because you down-voted, and I fail to see why a big comment means that I need to "cool down". You can down-vote whenever you want, I'm not here to stop you.

Comment: You can read all the pros and cons in the debate here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html?rq=1

My answer may not be the "best" answer, but it's an answer that'll work in this situation to get the job done.